# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible with sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am building a classifier for 7 classes where my array shapes are as follows:

```
X_train data shape - (171812, 384)
y_train data shape - (171812,)
X_test data shape - (37715, 384)
y_test data shape - (37715,)
```

my model is like this:

```
   # parameters 
input_dim= 10000 
max_length =384 
output_dim =128 DENSE_DIM = 32
DENSE_DIM = 32   
LSTM1_DIM = 32 
LSTM2_DIM = 16
WD = 0.001
FILTERS = 64  
   
   model_lstm = tf.keras.Sequential([
       tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=max_length),
   #    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, input_shape = (384,128)),
       tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM1_DIM, dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(WD), return_sequences=True)), 
       tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM2_DIM, dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(WD))),
       tf.keras.layers.Dense(DENSE_DIM, activation='relu'),     
       tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax') ])
   
   # Set the training parameters 
model_lstm.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
                      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
                       
   
   model_lstm.summary()
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_31 (Embedding)    (None, 384, 128)          1280000   
                                                                
bidirectional_67 (Bidirecti  (None, 384, 64)          41216     
onal)                                                           
                                                                
bidirectional_68 (Bidirecti  (None, 32)               10368     
onal)                                                           
                                                                
dense_108 (Dense)           (None, 32)                1056      
                                                                
dense_109 (Dense)           (None, 7)                 231       
                                                                
=================================================================
```

I am having ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible when I run:

```
epochs = 12
batch_size = 250

history = model_lstm.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
          batch_size=batch_size)
```

What should I be changing?

Also I am using an embedding layer for this model with 3 parameters (input_dim, output_dim, input_length). When I use an LTSM layer instead

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, input_shape = (384,128))
```

does not have a compatible input shape?

```
  Input 0 of layer "lstm_106" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 384)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential_53" "                 f"(type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 384), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Do I need to change the X_train data shape somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: `input_shape` does not include batch size, so you should do `input_shape=(384, 128)`.

Comment: It is probably an issue in your labels, try to check the unique values of your labels as they must be equal to 7 which your output layer shape

Comment: thank you, maciek97x, that works! but I still cant solve the ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible` error message is caused by the accuracy metric you choose, because the model output has shape `(None, 7)` and labels are `(None, 1)`.

To solve it you can simply remove this metric from compilation step:

```py
model_lstm.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
)
```

or convert your labels to one-hot encoding like:

```py
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(
    y_train, num_classes=7
)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(
    y_test, num_classes=7
)
```

and change loss to categorical crossentropy

```
model_lstm.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
)
```

Comment: When I used input_shape = (384,128), I got this  WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 384, 128) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 384, 128), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_93_input'), name='lstm_93_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_93_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 384).

Comment: I have slightly changed my question about the LSTM layer because of this.

Comment: Did you change anything else? I just converted inputs to categorical and set `input_shape=(384,128)` in LSTM layer and I was able to run training.